# react native starter cli project ios running error

Tags: ios, react-native

I'm running react native ios app.

```
yarn run:ios
```

I'm getting this error.

**error: unable to attach DB: error: accessing build database ".../ios/build/XCBuildData/build.db": database is locked Possibly there are two concurrent builds running in the same filesystem location.**

I've tried many solutions but still have this issue.
Anyone help me with this issue?